# How to remove bounty completely using console commands?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have created problems at many places in Skyrim thinking I would use bend will shout and now I want it to get cleared.

The problem is I don't have saved games and `set.playergoldcrime 0` is not working it is just reducing the bounty on me.

How can I remove the bounty completely?

Answer (score 4):

`[player.]paycrimegold <X> <Y> <FactionID>`

- < X> : remove stolen items (0 to keep, 1 to remove)
- < Y> : go to jail (0 not to go, 1 to go)

So what *you* want is `paycrimegold 0 0`

Comment: For Skyrim SE I had to use the FactionID and specify player. E.g. **player.paycrimegold 0 0 29DB0** to clear my Haafingar bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Select a guard, open console, and type **paycrimegold 0 0** to avoid paying money and going to jail.

You can also pay the fine by talking to a guard and get your money back. If you want your money back, type into console **player.additem f number_of_coins**.

Comment: Why would he want his money back if he didn't pay in the first place ?

Comment: You're right. Let me fix it.